# There is any tool for UI Unit Testing iPhone application(Not SenTestCase)

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, user-interface

I am looking for any tool or approach using which I can do UI unit test for iPhone application, I am aware of SenTestCase framework however which is used to do that testing for code I am looking for UI unit testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use OCUnit/SenTest to do unit tests in the UI as well as on the other code - [this blog post](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=205) from Chris Hanson is about Cocoa UI unit testing but the same principles apply to Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Thank you Graham Lee It seems very good to me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

Check out UISpec http://code.google.com/p/uispec/

It's an open source ui testing framework being developed for the iphone.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try libcat for UI testing and automation.
also providing console mode.

interactive iPhone application development

https://github.com/wookay/libcat

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to build a special testing target for your app, you can use the Ruby-based Cucumber framework to drive an iPhone GUI remotely: http://www.slideshare.net/undees/iphone-meets-cucumber

--Ian

Answer (score 1):

There is also Fone Monkey which allows you to record actions and then add assertions.

http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey

Answer (score 0):

Google has a pretty cool set of tools as well.

http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting